# Why is it showing me java.lang.StackOverflow error

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I have created a class, one instance  variable is created inside main method and another is outside.

```
// calling a method from constructor
public class Raw4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Raw4 r = new Raw4();
    }

    Raw4 r1 = new Raw4();

}
```

Comment: This class is not complete if you are *calling a method from constructor* because there is no method in your code but the `main`.

Comment: You create infinite r1, becuase each r1 will have an r1. Do you want it to be static?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new Raw4 object, all fields with initializers are initialized.

Your Raw4 class has a field named 'r1', of type Raw4, and it is initialized by creating... another Raw4 object.

So, the act of creating a Raw4 object involves creating a Raw4 object. That's a never-ending process.

Comment: Okay, got my answer, thanks much

Comment: Well, to be correct, actually it's ending, namely when run out of memory or cause a stack overflow. :)

Comment: @AlexR - Indeed, by a similar logic, there is no such thing as an infinite loop.   Eventually the computer stops working :-)